# Using GitHub API to retrieve all versions of a specific file

Tags: github-api

I am currently trying to read through the (GitHub API)[http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/] to figure out how I can programmatically retrieve all versions of a specific file in a single repository.

I see that one can get the list of commits, and the current version of a single file easily. But, is there a way to list all the commits relevant for a specific file and then iterate through all the versions of that file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the list of commits relevant for a specific file, use [this API endpoint](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) and specify the `path` parameter:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=FILE_PATH
```

You'll get back an array of commit objects, each of which has a `sha` attribute.

Now that you have all the commit SHAs, you can fetch all the different versions of the file using [this API endpoint](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) and by specifying the `ref` query parameter to set the SHA. So, for each commit SHA, make a request to:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:FILE_PATH?ref=SHA
```

and read the `content` attribute. Notice that the content is Base64 encoded, but you can also request a raw version by setting the relevant `Accept` [HTTP header](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types).

Comment: For actually getting the file, using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OWNER/REPO/SHA/FILE_PATH is not rate limited unlike api.github.com (if you are not authenticated)