# Getting all versions of a file using GitHub blob api

Tags: git, web-services, api, github, version-control

I want to know how to get all commits/versions of a file (i.e. the contents of the commits/versions) via the GitHub API.
I figured one way to do it which is equivalent to the answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700297/using-github-api-to-retrieve-all-versions-of-a-specific-file/16707165#16707165).

The problem is this uses the "contents" API, which has an upper limit of 1 MB per file (you get this error message if you try to access a file larger than 1 MB: "`This API returns blobs up to 1 MB in size. The requested blob is too large to fetch via the API, but you can use the Git Data API to request blobs up to 100 MB in size.`")

So to get files larger than 1 MB (up to 100 MB) you need to use the "blob" API, but I don't know how to use it in the same way as the contents API.

I.e., given a specific commit of a file, how do you get the contents of that file using the "blob" API?

Comment: Note: The  GitHub Content API now (May 2022) [support up to 100MB files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108664/6309).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [get content API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) indeed allows to pass a SHA1:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:FILE_PATH?ref=SHA
```

Note: The  GitHub Content API now (May 2022) [support up to 100MB files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108664/6309).

The [Blob API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#get-a-blob) also uses a SHA1:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/blobs/:sha
```

But you need to get the SHA1 of the file you want first.

See "[How do I get the “sha” parameter from GitHub API without downloading the whole file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204232/6309)", using the [Get Tree API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/) for the parent folder.

```
GET /repos/<owner>/<repo>/git/trees/url_encode(<branch_name>:<parent_path>)
```

'`url_encode(<branch_name>:<parent_path>)`' means the `<branch_name>:<parent_path>` needs to be [url encoded](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

The result from the tree will give you the SHA1 of the file you are looking for.

The [OP buddyroo30](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5715113/buddyroo30) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456176/getting-all-versions-of-a-file-using-github-blob-api/34460532#comment56944093_34460532):

> I ended up doing similarly using the tree API.
> Specifically, I get all the commits for a file. Then I try to use the contents API to get the file contents for each commit.
> If that fails (i.e. over 1 MB in size so I need to use the blob API), I get the tree URL for the file from its commit (i.e. in Perl: `$commit_tree_url = $commit_info->{'commit'}->{'tree'}->{'url'}`).
> then I fetch `$commit_tree_url` and find the correct tree record in the results for the file --- this will have a 'url' hash value which can be used to get the file contents via the blob API.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing similarly using the tree API. Specifically, I get all the commits for a file. Then I try to use the contents API to get the file contents for each commit. If that fails (i.e. over 1 MB in size so I need to use the blob API), I get the tree URL for the file from its commit (i.e. in Perl: $commit_tree_url = $commit_info->{'commit'}->{'tree'}->{'url'}). then I fetch $commit_tree_url and find the correct tree record in the results for the file --- this will have a 'url' hash value which can be used to get the file contents via the blob API.

Comment: @buddyroo30 Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.