# How to automatically get a certain file(>1MB) from git

Tags: git, github

I want to grab a certain file from a private git repository daily under linux.
I've got no problem with files under 1MB via [Get content API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) with curl command as follows.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O $FILEPATH
```

As the file gets bigger than 1MB now, I have no idea how to do this now.

Git tells me to use the [Git Data API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#get-a-blob) to get a blob(up to 100MB, more than enough for me).

Though I've been trying to find a way to grab the SHA1 of the frequently updating file, I haven't came across any applicable method yet. Any suggestion?

Or maybe method other than using git API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If file path in the repository is known, you can receive its SHA using [Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents). For example:

```
~ λ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3" \
    https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/contents/README.md

{
  "name": "README.md",
  "path": "README.md",
  "sha": "36bba4cf1f8fd3cbbdf81d4cc2291b54a4e56a63",
  "size": 16,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/contents/README.md?ref=master",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/smt116/dotfiles/blob/master/README.md",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/git/blobs/36bba4cf1f8fd3cbbdf81d4cc2291b54a4e56a63",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smt116/dotfiles/master/README.md",
  "type": "file",
  "content": "IyMgTXkgZG90ZmlsZXMuCg==\n",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/contents/README.md?ref=master",
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/git/blobs/36bba4cf1f8fd3cbbdf81d4cc2291b54a4e56a63",
    "html": "https://github.com/smt116/dotfiles/blob/master/README.md"
  }
}
```

Now you can download the file with [Git Data API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#get-a-blob) using `git_url` link that is included in the JSON response.

However if you want to download all blobs from a given repository, you can use [Git Trees](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/) to fetch the list first. You need to specify commit SHA but you can use HEAD if the most recent commit is okay. For example:

```
~ λ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" \
      https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/git/trees/HEAD

{
  "sha": "0fc96d75ff4182913cec229978bb10ad338012fd",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/git/trees/0fc96d75ff4182913cec229978bb10ad338012fd",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": ".agignore",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "e2ca571728887bce8255ab3f66061dde53ffae4f",
      "size": 21,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/git/blobs/e2ca571728887bce8255ab3f66061dde53ffae4f"
    },
    {
      "path": ".bundle",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "4148d567286de6aa47047672b1f2f73d7bea349b",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smt116/dotfiles/git/trees/4148d567286de6aa47047672b1f2f73d7bea349b"
    },
    ...
```

To get details of all files including subdirectories, you have to add `recursive=1` query parameter to the URL.

Then you need to parse JSON response, filter those items that have `blob` type and download files using `url` attributes.

Comment: What is `~ λ`? Your shell prompt?

Comment: Yes, it is my shell prompt.

Comment: When indicating the shell prompt, consider replacing it by a more canonical one like `> `, `$ ` or `$> `, so that it'll be more widely recognized as what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though I don't think Content API will work in my case due to file size, I should be able to work it out with Tree API. I didn't know that you can use HEAD instead of sha for Tree API thanks for the hint.

Comment: @H.Jiang as I said in the response you can use content Api just to fetch url for blob and use it for download. It will work.

Comment: @H.Jiang is it working for you or is there something that I should explain further? Is it answers your question?

Comment: @smefju I'm so sorry for the terribly late reply. I should definitely check stackoverflow more often.  Thanks to your suggestion, I'm using Tree API to identify SHA and get the file with Blob API! As for content API, I still don't see how you could get url for a blob larger than 1MB with the same command you used above. I could only get a response that tells me to use Git Data API.

Comment: Oh, did you mean that I should use content API to fetch information for the directory?

Comment: Yes. You can fetch information using Contents API or Git Trees and then download files using Git Data API.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easier now (May 2022) using just the filepath, since the Get repository Content API finally support raw content up to 100MB instead of 1MB.

> ### [Increased file size limit when retrieving file contents via REST API](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-03-increased-file-size-limit-when-retrieving-file-contents-via-rest-api/)
>
> Previously, the **[Get repository content](https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content)** REST API endpoint had a file size limit of 1 MB.
> That didn’t correspond to the [Create or update file contents](https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/contents#create-or-update-file-contents) endpoint which has a file size limit of 100 MB.
>
> **Now, both endpoints have a file size limit of 100 MB**.
>
> However, requests for file contents larger than 1 MB must include the [`.raw` custom media type](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#custom-media-types-for-repository-contents) in the `Accept` HTTP header, as shown here:
>
> ```
>  Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw
> ```
>
> Read more about [GitHub's REST API endpoints for repository contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents).

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
     https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH
```

> Between 1-100 MB: Only the raw or object custom media types are supported.
> Both will work as normal, except that when using the object media type, the content field will be an empty string and the encoding field will be "`none`". >
> To get the contents of these larger files, use the raw media type.
>
> Greater than 100 MB: This endpoint is not supported.